# Validate Switch Enabled Teaming Configurations Cluster Validation Failure

Tags: failovercluster, windows-server-2022

Setting up failover Clusters using windows Server 2022.

Both nodes are server 2022 fully patched.

Both nodes are running on VMware ESXI/vSphere

> Validate Switch Enabled Teaming Configurations
> Description: Validate that Switch Enabled Teaming configuration, if present, is consistent between cluster nodes.
> Start: 1/31/2022 12:34:31 PM.
> Validating Switch Embedded Teaming Settings.
> An error occurred while executing the test.
> Unable to connect to SQL22-DEV-N01.DOMAIN.org via WMI. This may be due to networking issues or firewall configuration on SQL22-DEV-N01.DOMAIN.org.
>
> Invalid namespace Stop: 1/31/2022 12:34:31 PM.

Is Microsoft requiring Teams for Clusters using server 2022 or is this a bug?

Thoughts on how to work around this issue?

Thoughts?

EDIT:
i found this is similar to the issue we are having..
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/589879/server-2022-cluster-validation-network-invalid-nam.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is still getting this error.. As of December 2022, simply do a windows update on all your cluster nodes and the issue will be sorted. Microsoft seems to have fixed the issue on the April update.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue with it while creating clusters, The workaround we used is to skip Validate Switch Enabled Teaming Configuration in the Cluster validation test.

Its a hack, i would not recommend it for production servers.

Microsoft has not shared any bug id for this issue as of now.